# Samba - Hide unauthorized directories

Tags: linux, networking, samba, smb

I currently have a number of read-only directories shared for the public. There are a number of other shares that only I have access to. Hence when other people try to access the shares, they are asked for a username/password.

I now want to hide these shares to everyone on the network, except those with valid login credentials (aka: me). Currently my security is set to share (that everyone else can access the public shares). I’ve followed a lot of tutorials, but nothing helps. Here is what I’ve tried:

```
hide unreadable = yes (still shows for unauthorized users)
browseable = no (hides it, but also for authorized users)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to do something similar and also tried the browseable flag.

But as it hides it for everyone, it wasn't a good solution.

I was sharing these folders on a linux host (Open Media Vault which is a NAS oriented distribution). I finally used an option to give access to samba users to "Home folders".

If i'm not wrong, each user will only see it's own Home folder.

PS: When i did so, i had to manually create each Home folders for each user.